# Installing pdftk on Amazon EC2 Linux Instance

Tags: java, gcc, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, pdftk

I am having trouble installing [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit) on an `amzn-ami-2011.09.2.x86_64-ebs` (`ami-953b06e1`) instance.

Since pdftk is not in the [list of available packages](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2012.03-packages/) I have tried to build it from source but failed due to a missing dependency – `cgj`, Java GNU Compiler, which also isn't available in the packages list.

I have already installed `gcc`, `gcc-c++` and `make` besides the default packages.

Answer (score 1):

Running PDFtk on Amazon Linux is possible. I wrote a blog post about running PDFtk on AWS Lambda, which runs on Amazon Linux: https://lob.com/blog/aws-lambda-pdftk/.

It should be entirely possible to use the binary I compiled, along with libgcj.so to run PDFtk on an Amazon Linux EC2. The binary and shared library in this repository should work for you: https://github.com/lob/lambda-pdftk-example

**Update**

The basics steps to get PDFtk running on Amazon Linux are to compile it from source on CentOS 6, then copy the `pdftk` binary and `libgcj.so.10` (usually located in `/usr/lib64/` to your Amazon Linux machine.

Place the binary in a directory in your `PATH`, and `libgcj.so.10` in a directory in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so the system knows where to find them.

Alternatively you can run the binary directly:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libgcj.so.10 /path/to/pdftk --version`

You can skip the compile step by using the binary and shared library in the `bin/` directory of the Github project I linked to above.

Comment: It would be better if you included the basic steps in the answer.

Comment: @Ayan good suggestion. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You may be out of luck: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=96919

> GCJ is not supported on the Amazon Linux AMI, which is why you are running into this problem.